# SQL Server - Change unknown number of row values into column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as such:

```
process_id      process_info      value       date
------------------------------------------------------
    A               chop            3         2020-05
    A               chop            4         2020-07
    A               extrude         6         2020-01
    B               something       2         2019-52
    B               something       4         2020-05
```

As you can see this table represents changes to a value for a certain process_info and process_id over time (year-week). However I want to make the date row values into column names and represent the data that way. Pivot doesn't work since I don't know every value in date column.

I want to get to this:

```
process_id      process_info            2019_52_values   2020_01_values      2020_05_values
     B              something                2                                     4
     A              extrude                                    6
     A               chop                                                          3
```

and so forth.

Comment: You either have to go dynamic SQL or use a different tool. SQL queries always produce a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their names and their types.

Comment: or, as the possible years and weeks are predictable just hardcode all values far into the future

Answer (score 0):

I had an similar problem. I solved it, by generating a dynamic SQL in T-SQL.
I first queried the columns. Then i created a pivot sql for data collection.
This query i executed with `EXEC sp_executesql @Query`

Finally all this was wrapped into a stored procedure.

Tipp:
When creating column names make sure they are valid: `QUOTENAME()` is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL for that.

try the following:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols_to_display NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols_to_display = STUFF(
                                (
                                 SELECT DISTINCT 
                                        ','+QUOTENAME(t.[date])+ ' as '''+replace(t.[date], '-', '_')+'_values'''
                                 FROM TestTable t FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
                            );
SET @cols = STUFF(
                    (
                     SELECT DISTINCT 
                            ','+QUOTENAME(t.[date])
                     FROM TestTable t FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
                );
SET @query = 'SELECT process_id, process_info, '+@cols_to_display+'
                FROM (
                        SELECT process_id, process_info, [value], [date]
                        FROM TestTable
                     )x 
                     PIVOT
                     (
                        SUM([value]) FOR [date] in ('+replace(@cols, '_values', '')+')
                     ) pvt';
print @query
EXECUTE (@query);
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=154dcc22ff5fc05c1cd50009e4fbf4b2)** (another method is also provided there).